# Compatible value's position in an editable ComboBox

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a ComboBox implemented with an auto-completion system. My ComboBox contains more than 100 items. When users are typing text in, the auto-completion system opens the dropdown list and highlights the most relevant item. Moreover, when the dropdown list is expanded, all items are available (no filters). But the most relevant item is always at the bottom of the dropdown list.

I would like it to be in the middle, if possible. One item can have the same reference but another type than another one, that's why I need to see most of them in my dropdown by placing them in the middle.

Any idea ? It's not really important but kind of useful for them. Thanks !

**Update :**

[image: Screenshot]

Here's my ComboBox with the open dropdown. Sorry about that, I had to blur its elements. As you can see, the user starts writting the reference in the ComboBox. The autocompletion works fine, but the corresponding item is found at the end of the dropdown list (in the red frame), almost out of bounds.

I wish it would be highlighted in the middle of my dropdown list instead of so far below.

Comment: No filters, but "most relevant items are at the bottom" ? You could add a custom sorting for your ItemsSource. That you would achieve adding your sort-function to CollectionViewSource.Filter property. But I don't see if that's really what you want?

Comment: Hmm... actually it's a bit too much. I mean, I first wanted to know if there was a property in my ComboBox to do that, or not. The idea is that I can't really sort my source, but I keep your suggestion in mind.

Comment: You added some more confusion, and it looks you find it not important anymore yourself. Feel free to describe what you really want.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't really know how to describe my problem. See my update for more info. It's not really important since it works, but my users would think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your item search may work well, but your list isn't visually filtered, which means it's size always remains the same.
It's scrolled into view, by the wpf system, but still displaying all other items around the relevant one. The reason why it's at the bottom is because wpf Scrollviewer just finished scrolling the item into view and sees no need to scroll it further into the middle.

You could use the CollectionViewSource class. Why ?

It's simple to use, will keep your viewmodel data as it is, and you would have your relevant completion item at the top. It can be obtained by GetDefaultView(..)

Let's say you have a viewmodel flag "IsHidden", stating that it's content does not match the user input:

```
ICollectionView cv= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myComboBox.ItemsSource);

// switch filter on
cv.Filter = obj => (obj as myViewModel).IsHidden == false;
// switch off
cv.Filter = null
```

Comment: Yes, I got the first point. I tried your example, but it doesn't fit in my CB. I'm not supposed to modify its behaviour so much, because it involves a lot of other things. Though, I see how I'd do, and as I wanted to know if it was a CB property, your answer seems to be the easier way to do that. Thanks !